# How can I strip Windows drive lettering out of my reformed path? Delphi or Pascal

Tags: delphi, freepascal, conditional-compilation

Further to [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278513/lazarus-free-pascal-how-to-recursively-copy-a-source-directory-of-files-to-a/9397718#9397718) I have another sticky problem. My coding is Free Pascal but Delphi solutions will work probably.

In brief, I have a string value of concatenated paths that is formed by taking a source directory and recreating that tree in a destination directory. e.g.

C:\SourceDir\SubDirA 
becomes 
F:\DestinationDir\SourceDir\SubDirA.

However, the solution I have for the Linux version of my program (as posted in the link above) doesn't quite work with Windows version because I end up with :

F:\DestionationDir\C:SourceDir\SubDirA.

which is invalid.

So I came up with this "only run in Windows" code to remove the central drive letterof the reformed path, but leave the initial one at the start by saying "Look at the string starting from the 4th character in from the left. If you find 'C:', delete it" so that the path becomes F:\DestinationDir\SourceDir\SubDirA.

```
{$IFDEF Windows} // Only do this for the Windows version
    k := posex('C:', FinalisedDestDir, 4);  // Find 'C:' in the middle of the concatanated path and return its position as k
    Delete(FinalisedDestDir, k, 2);  // Delete the 2 chars 'C:' of 'C:\' if found, leaving the '\' to keep the path valid
{$ENDIF}
```

Now, that works fine IF the C: is the source of the chosen directory. But obviously if the user is copying data from another drive (such as E:, F:, G: or whatever else drive up to Z:) it will not work.

So my question is, how do I code it so that it says "if any drive letter a: to z: is found after the 4th character from the left, delete it"? Whilst any solution that works "will do", ideally I need a fast solution. The best solution would be to not have it in there in the first place, but given the solution I posted in reply to my earlier post, I can't work out how not to have it in, due to the procedure I use to form it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a code I use in my application:

```
function CombinePath(const BaseDir, Path: string): string;
begin
  if IsPathDelimiter(Path, 1) then
    Result := ExcludeTrailingBackSlash(BaseDir) + Path else
    Result := IncludeTrailingBackSlash(BaseDir) + Path;
end;

function MapRootPath(const Path, NewPath: string): string;
var
  Drive, RelativePath: string;
begin
  Drive := ExtractFileDrive(Path); // e.g: "C:"
  RelativePath := ExtractRelativePath(Drive, Path); // e.g: "Program Files\MyApp"
  Result := CombinePath(NewPath, RelativePath);
end;
```

Usage:

```
ShowMessage(MapRootPath('C:\SourceDir\SubDirA', 'F:\DestionationDir'));
// result is "F:\DestionationDir\SourceDir\SubDirA"
```

Answer (score 3):

I offer you two solutions:

#### Normalize your paths *before* concatenating folders

You know the saying, prevention is always better then the cure. Why don't you "normalize" paths *before* you do your concatentations? This gives you the chance to:

- Delete the drive letter from the path if the name starts with a path. If the second char in the string is `:` and the third is `\` you know it's a Windows path containing a drive letter. You may delete all of the first 3 characters.
- Deal with UNC names, you didn't mention those: `\\ComputerName\ShareName\SubFolder`
- Fix slashes so they conform to your current platform

#### Remove the drive letter later

This is ugly (because you shouldn't get into this situation in the first place), but you can always look for `:\` - not for `C:`. The `:` is not valid in folder or file names on windows, so if you find it you know it's preceded by exactly one char, and that's the DRIVE letter. Get the index for `:\`, substract `, delete 2 chars from that index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know freepascal but for this problem use regular expression such as [A-Za-z]\: to find such string. I see from freepascal wiki that it supports regular expressions http://wiki.freepascal.org/Regexpr.

Answer (score 0):

You might also see if some of the SysUtils functions can help, including:

- ExpandFileName()
- IncludeTrailingSlashes()
- etc..

Putting your path in a "normalized" form - like these functions might be able to do for you - makes it trivial to convert between Linux and Windows path conventions.

Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help with this. Special thanks to kobik who's code sample is very clear and easy to follow. That is certainly one way to do it, but whilst I was waiting for replies I came up with the following which also seems to work quite well for me :

```
type
TRange = 'A'..'Z';
...

{$IFDEF Windows}
    // Due to the nonsenseories of Windows, we have to allow for driver lettering.

  for DriveLetter in TRange do
      begin
        k := posex(DriveLetter+':', FinalisedDestDir, 4);  // Find e.g 'C:' in the middle of the concatanated path and return its position, leaving the first 'C:\' at the start in place
        Delete(FinalisedDestDir, k, 2);  // Delete 'C:' of 'C:\' if found, leaving the '\'
      end;
{$ENDIF}
```